# USB drive doesn't work after mounting ubuntu

Tags: usb

My USB drive doesn't even show up in the device manager so I can't even format it. Its a Lexar Jumpdrive 64 gig. Please how am I going to make it work again?

Comment: After you insert you pendrive and wait for 10 seconds, please edit your question with the output of `sudo fdisk -l`.

Comment: After inserting the drive, what does dmesg |tail  show for USB activity?

Answer (score 0):

Is it formatted?
Open up Gparted and see if it detects it and let us know 
what information Gparted has about it.